# Can't load Xfce due to login loop, other DEs work

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, login, xfce, desktop-environments

I'm a newbie on Ubuntu. I wanted to install XFCE to create a very personal DE.

The problem is I've got a login loop. Since I upgraded my distro to 17.10 to support my wifi, I can't load XFCE.
But I can load Unity and Ubuntu DE.m

When I try to login, it loops again on the login screen.

I know it's a graphical error but I can't fix it with the usual commands.

Comment: How did you add XFCE to your Ubuntu 17.10.  If you added `xubuntu-desktop` you'll have the complete [xfce] system, but its possible if you added it by packages, some are missing causing this issue.  There are other reasons for login loop (eg. no space in $HOME) but because you can't login only with xfce, implies an xfce issue to me.

Comment: I've installed just xfce4 in package. I didn't want the complete system.

Comment: It will probably work much better if you start from a simple text mode system (a fresh install from the Ubuntu `mini.iso` or in UEFI mode from the Ubuntu Server iso file). Then you can add whatever program packages, that you want. XFCE should work well, but you can even install a simple window manager without a full desktop environment, or create an own very personal DE. Good luck :-) By the way, you may be interested in Xubuntu Core, that you can get via this command line (after installing `zsync`), `zsync http://unit193.net/xubuntu/core/pending/xubuntu-18.04-core-amd64.iso.zsync`

Comment: Thanks ;) but for the begging I'll keep trying XFCE if it works. To know how to do ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to get a system with only `xfce4` in Bionic Beaver, 18.04 LTS

- Download and check an **Ubuntu `mini.iso`** file,

  or to boot in **UEFI mode**, from an **Ubuntu Server** 64-bit (amd64) iso file),

  a 32-bit system

  ```
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-i386/current/images/MD5SUMS
  grep mini.iso MD5SUMS | sed s#./netboot/## > mini.md5
  md5sum -c mini.md5
  ```

  or a 64-bit system,

  ```
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/MD5SUMS
  grep mini.iso MD5SUMS | sed s#./netboot/## > mini.md5
  md5sum -c mini.md5
  ```
- Create a CD/DVD/USB boot drive by cloning from the `mini.iso` file
- Install a minimal system from `mini.iso` CD/DVD/USB.

  You need a wired connection to the internet (ethernet) for the `mini.iso` to work.

  <sup>It might be possible, but is difficult, to make WiFi work with the `mini.iso` installer. (I don't know how to do it.)</sup>
- Boot into the installed minimal system. You arrive at a text screen.

  After `login:` please **enter the user ID** (that you created a few minutes ago), **and after that the password**. There is no echo (no dots) when you enter the password.

  Now you can run command lines.
- Install 'only ' `xfce4`. You will get no graphical greeter unless you install it separately.

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install xfce4
  ```
- Now you can start the graphical session with the command

  ```
  startx
  ```

  and it will look like the following picture (I ran some commands before taking the screenshot),

  [image]

  If you right-click on the picture and open it in another window (that is big enough), you can see it in full size and read the text.

### How to get a system with `xfce4` alongside standard Ubuntu with `gnome`in Bionic Beaver, 18.04 LTS

- **Warning about mixing desktop environments**

  It is easy to install new desktop environments alongside the current one, but it is very difficult to remove that desktop environment without damage to the desktop environment, that you want to keep. So *don't do this to your production operating system unless you have a good backup.*
- Install standard Ubuntu Bionic, 18.04 LTS
- Boot into the installed system
- Install `xfce4` and `lxde` to help `xfce` work alongside standard Ubuntu

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install xfce4 lxde
  ```
- Reboot (next time you can also log out and switch session without reboot)
- Click on the cog wheel symbol to select session (XFCE, LXDE, Ubuntu ...)

  [image]
- Enter password and log in.

Comment: I had already done everything listed here, except install LXDE. Now it works. Do you know why that is necessary?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann, I found that it works after installing LXDE, but I sorry, I don't know why (what is missing, when only XFCE is added).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Start in text-only mode

```
Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.
Select the line which starts with Advanced options.
Select the line ending with (recovery mode)
Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.
After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt. Press Return with this option highlighted.
The PC will start in a terminal.
```

Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
apt install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of gnome & unity that are not necessary in Xubuntu

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Reinstall xubuntu-desktop

```
apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
deborphan
apt --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
apt autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
apt clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this tonight and I'll tell you what's return

Comment: The OP wants XFCE, not the whole `xubuntu-desktop`. Does your method work also in this case, maybe with some modification?

Comment: Yes.  Change apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop   to apt install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop.