# Trying to install xfce4 on Ubuntu server 18.04.1

Tags: apt, server, software-installation, 18.04

I've been a long time user of xubuntu and finally bit the bullet and installed the server version as I am running this PC mainly for fileserver and streaming purposes.

That said, I'm trying to install xfce4 as the GUI, but even though every webpage states just use `apt-get` or just `apt install xfce4` am met with the following:

> Reading package list... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: unable to locate package xfce4

This seems to be the same for any files pertaining to xubuntu.
I'm guessing there may be something lacking in my resources list,

But if this is the case....why do so many webpages just advise to install xfce4 and then lightdm??

I'm a stubborn @#£11!! and have no intention to go back to an xubuntu install as it takes an age to remove all the shash I don't want, so would rather get it right first time...

Comment: I can't even install Joe my goto file editor either...

Comment: May I be so bold as to suggest you visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026862/cant-load-xfce-de for a solution?

Comment: Those packages are in 'universe', and it's not enabled by default in 'server', so must be enabled first, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you guiverc....I looked at the command line version of this page and added the universe repo via nano, my thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

Comment: universe repository already enabled in 18.04

Comment: This worked for me. It was not enabled in default DigitalOcean image.